# The longest sequence-A short puzzle

Tags: number-sequence

Complete the following sequence!

**5, 13, 17, 25, 29, 37, 41, 53, 65, 65,____, _____** and it goes on..

Edit: I added 53, 65, 65 to the sequence to make it more specific.

Comment: I'm vtc this as too broad after seeing the oeis results for this sequence which are numerous

Comment: Oh! I forgot to notice the obvious. I had edited and added terms to make it specific.

Comment: See, I'm afraid, https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/number-sequence-puzzles-what-not-to-do

Comment: Oh! I am quite new here. Understood my mistake. Will take care of that in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first match found by an [OEIS search](http://oeis.org/search?q=5%2C+13%2C+17%2C+25%2C+29%2C+37%2C+41&language=english&go=Search) for the first few terms matches all the rest, and indicates that these are

> hypotenuse lengths of primitive Pythagorean triples, in ascending order, without removing duplicates.

So, e.g., there are two 65s because

> $65=5\times13$ has two prime factors that are 1 mod 4, which leads to there being two ways to write $65^2$ as the sum of two squares: $63^2+16^2$ and $56^2+33^2$.

The title is because

> the hypotenuse is the *longest* side of a right-angled triangle.

Answer (score 3):

Is it simply

> 49, 53 ? Or I missed something :-)

Comment: Why do you think this is the answer? Unexplained answers are not useful (except maybe for questions where they are obvious once stated).

Comment: Looks like it. The pattern seems to be: +8, +4, +8, +4,....

Comment: That would be ... very disappointing.

Comment: But it does look like that's consistent with the sequence so far, so it's VTC too-broad territory if that *isn't* the intended answer.

Comment: didn't see the comments here before i answered. answer is listed.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan [ahem](http://oeis.org/search?q=5%2C+13%2C+17%2C+25%2C+29%2C+37%2C+41&language=english&go=Search)

Comment: I had edited the question to make it more specific and not so obvious :).